# Visual Studio 2008 BuildEvent Macros not Firing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, macros

I added this well documented macro to MyMacros, Environment Events in VS 2008 Macros in order to cancel failed builds:

```
Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildProjConfigDone(ByVal Project As String, ByVal ProjectConfig As String, ByVal Platform As String, ByVal SolutionConfig As String, ByVal Success As Boolean) Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildProjConfigDone

    If Success = False Then
        'The build failed...cancel any further builds.
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Build.Cancel")
    End If
```

But it's not canceling my builds.  I also set breakpoints to hopefully catch it firing but they are not hit either.

I also added this test macro but its not being fired either:

```
Private Sub BuildEvents_OnBuildBegin(ByVal Scope As EnvDTE.vsBuildScope, ByVal Action As EnvDTE.vsBuildAction) Handles BuildEvents.OnBuildBegin
    Beep()
    Beep()
End Sub
```

The "Allow macros to run" option is set.

Why is it not being fired?  Why are my breakponts not being hit?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you have to run Debug (green play button) in the Macros IDE for breakpoints to be hit.

Now I know.